# Apache won't load/parse .php

Tags: windows, php, apache-2.2, installation

I just clean installed Apache 2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.4.  For Apache selected Win32 installer, for PHP I selected x86 VC6 Thread Safe due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php/4239206), and I put Apache in C:\web\Apache2.2, and PHP in C:\web\libraries\PHP.

The thing is every time I try to hit a PHP page on localhost, I get this entry in my log files:

```
[Thu Dec 16 11:54:02 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/web/htdocs/web, referer: http://localhost/
```

DocumentRoot is C:\web\htdocs, and it works fine for normal .html files (*it works!*). But
it seems Apache is redirecting all requests for .php pages.. to a subfolder called /web of htdocs.  I don't get it.

All the PHP installer did was in httpd.conf:

```
ScriptAlias /php/ "C:/web/libraries/php/"
Action application/x-httpd-php "C:/web/libraries/php/php-cgi.exe"
```

And mime.types:

```
application/x-httpd-php php
application/x-httpd-php-source  phps
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/web/libraries/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Looks like the PHP people messed it up.

To get the ScriptAlias line above, I actually selected "Apache 2.2.x Module" in the PHP installer but it looks like it added PHP-CGI directives which was not what I want.

So naturally I chose "Apache CGI" to get it to configure for "Apache 2.2.x Module" ;)

Here's what I have in `httpd.conf` now:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/web/libraries/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/web/libraries/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"    
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I'm not sure if this is entirely correct, but it works.